# jquery code doesn't set the height from the very start?

Tags: jquery, html, loading

I'm using this simple snippet at the end of my code in order to make an element fill the remaining height available on the screen:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        vpw = $(window).width();
        vph = $(window).height();
        $('#author').css({'height': (vph - $('.navigation').height() - $('.menu').height()) + 'px'});
    });
```

However the height isn't modified from the very start. After I refresh the page, it will have the default height and the height will get modified like a second later, after all the child elements have loaded.

Comment: Yes, this delay will occur because the document.ready event will not fire until the document is *ready*. This can take a *second* sometimes

Comment: Is there any way I can make it execute the code before all the elements have loaded?

Comment: if you execute that script before all the elements are loaded, then `$('#author')` will not find the element with `#author`

Comment: Other than pure css solutions, I dont know of a jquery way to do this without a deley. Perhaps if you put up a fiddle SO can attempt a pure css solution

Comment: Are you trying to do animation navigation hight on scrolling or different windows screen?